# From client website pass parameters to webservice method using ajax/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two websites

1. SyncTestWebsite
2. RemoteWebsite (client website)

SysteTestWebsite contains a web service "Service.svc" with following method

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]<br>
public class Service
{

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string SyncJson(string p1)
    {
        return p1;
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

I want to access this method from a HTML Page of RemoteWebsite, Following is code of this HTML Page.

```
    function SyncJson() {
        var sPhone = "test data";
        var data = { p1: sPhone };
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;",
            url: "http://mydomain:12887/Service.svc/SyncJson",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    }


<p>
    Remote site
    <input type="button" onclick="SyncJson()" value="Send Test Data" />

</p>
```

But I got this error:

> NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed -
>   http://abc.com/Service.svc/SyncJson

Answer (score 0):

This is cross domain request. You should consider this when creating your service.
Read more about CORS.

Comment: Thanks Max! Can you please send me any working example of CORS web service.